# A trivial counter fails in PHP

Tags: php

I have a PHP script that updates a counter each time the page is retrieved.
After creating the file in `bash` with

```
echo -n 0 > counterfile.txt
```

the PHP page looks like this:

```
<?php
$count = 'counterfile.txt';
file_put_contents($count,1+file_get_contents($count),LOCK_EX);
?>
```

The thing works fine, I see the `counterfile.txt` being updated, but once in a while the counter is reset, or at least sometimes today's counter value is less than yesterday's.

Why is this? Maybe some base-10 problem...? Maybe for some reason this is safer:

```
<?php
$count = 'counterfile.txt';
$n = file_get_contents($count);
file_put_contents($count,($n++),LOCK_EX);
?>
```

Comment: what happens when one thread in the middle of writing this file, but another is trying to read?

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php#112831

Comment: Mmmm... I see. What does the 'rt' mean in `fopen('test.txt','rt');`? Shouldn't be 'r+' or 'w+'?

Comment: `rt` means read text file, it can be `r+` as well if you're doing writing before closing

Comment: `file_put_contents` can return `false` on failure - in this case, `1 + false = 1`

Comment: `$n = file_get_contents($count); if ($n === false) { /* failed to read */ }`. You can do a while loop to read until successful and then increment or just exit the script at that point to prevent an incorrect value being set.

Comment: @IłyaBursov: Actually, I thought that the `LOCK_EX` in `file_put_contents($count,($n++),LOCK_EX);` was equivalent to first flocking and then closing... no?

Comment: @LuisA.Florit yes, it locks during writing, so it prevents parallel writing to file, but it does not prevent reading from it, essentially you need flock around whole `read; increment; write` thing, you can use flock on **another** file, thus creating global critical section

Comment: @IłyaBursov I see. Probably better with a LOCK_EX instead of a LOCK_SH...?

Comment: @LuisA.Florit yeah, in this case `LOCK_EX` is better

Comment: @Rylee Mmmm... that would be crazy indeed... I don't think it can fail so easily, but I will take that into account. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that the file_get_contents is successful (not returning false) before proceeding to write (otherwise the counter will be re-set as 1, which is not desirable)

Hence:

```
<?php
$count = 'counterfile.txt';
$var1=file_get_contents($count);

if ($var1!=false){
file_put_contents($count, (1+$var1) ,LOCK_EX);
}

?>
```

Alternatively, you may use a **db** approach (increment a field value by one each time)